# i want to return the value of x from this function , here is the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, oop

```
getUD = (v) => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(v)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        let x = doc.data().name;
        console.log(x);
      });
    return "x";
  };
```

Comment: You can only return _a promise to the value of `x`_, not the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```js
getUD = (v) => {
  return firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(v)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      return doc.data().name;
    });
};
```

Comment: @KorenHamra this is because the `getUD` function is itself asynchronous and returns a promise. You need to use `then()` or `async/await` when you call it.

Comment: got it ! thanks  (;

Answer (score 0):

```js
getUD = async (v) => {
  const doc = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(v)
    .get();
  return doc.data().name;
};


getUD = (v) => {
  return firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(v)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      return doc.data().name;
    });
};
```

You can simply use `async`/ `await` or return from your then.